# Put a text on top of a button - android

Tags: java, android, button

i have a regular android button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_0"
style="@style/def_button_numb"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="0" />
```

First:
I need to put some text on top of this button, just like keyboards does.

And second:
On longpress needs to show a popup (also like keyboards), to let user choose two more options of buttons.

is there an ease way to do so?

Comment: Please at least attempt research before asking questions. We aren't here to do your work for you.

see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: Well, i tried to research, but i didn't found anything to do so, about put the text on top i already have a text on this button and must continue, i need put another text on the top of the button, about show popup on long click, i thought, as it has many apps that do this, there must be a simple native way to do it. But thanks anyway

Comment: What you want is literally linked in my answer, including examples, in a range of different languages. The android developer guide is actually helpful if you bother to read it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add this code

android:text="SEND DATA TO FRAGMENT B"